# Given a pandas dataframe that contains multiple dates and multiple times per date how can I select the times for each date?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've tried:

```
start_date = '2019-12-02'
end_date = '2019-12-02'
day_df = df[(df['timestamp'] >= start_date) & (df['timestamp'] <= end_date)]
```

which returns an empty Dataframe

I've also tried:

```
start_date = '2019-12-02' + ' 00:00:00'
end_date = '2019-12-02' + ' 23:59:59'
```

which also returns an empty Dataframe.

Edit:
Example Data

```
2019-12-02 06:41:54
2019-12-02 06:41:54
2019-12-03 00:38:56
2019-12-03 06:37:13
2019-12-03 06:52:09
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of timestamp column? is it DateTime?

Comment: What exactly is your desired output? To select all the entries between a certain time of the day you could do `df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)` and then `df.between_time(start_time, end_time)`.

Comment: @Ave799 its a column of Strings so that I can slice them. I tested to see if this was the problem by making start_date and end_date different String dates but that ended up working

Comment: @gofvonx my desired output is to get all the times for each date into a temporary dataframe so I can drop the data outside a certain time range, average the remaining data, and then create a new dataframe that has one value per date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments this might work:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)  # a DateTimeIndex is necessary to use between_time
start_time = '00:00:00'
end_time = '23:59:59'
df.between_time(start_time, end_time).resample('D').mean()
```